# MultiAutoCompleteTextView adds previously typed characters automatically to next selection

Tags: java, android, keyboard, multiautocompletetextview

I am using the following tutorial to implement a MultiAutoCompleteTextView : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

The problem I am facing is that let's say I select Belgium first by typing in 'be' and selecting from the drop-down that appears, then I type in "fr" to select France, but instead what appears is "befr". So the entire textview now shows "Belgium, befr".

I can't find the solution to this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same problem and could not find anything in the documentation. Then something strange happened. 
I went to the Google keyboard settings and disabled all autocorrect and suggestion options and voila ! The problem was resolved.

But
Now I have tried enabling all the keyboard features one by one but I am unable to replicate the issue. This is very weird but I think the problem is related to keyboard settings and not

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens only in certain devices. I have seen this with samsung devices only. The solution is DO NOT set the input type as TYPE_CLASS_TEXT on the phone where u see this issue.

To check if the device has this issue check for the flag isSuggestionsEnabled().

Catch here is that if the type the whole world as present in your suggestion and click on the suggestion option from the drop down menu. This problem comes back.

But still, this solution reduces the probability of user noticing the bug.